# Use Cantor's diagonal argument to prove

Tags: combinatorics

My exercise is : "Let A = {0, 1} and consider Fun(Z, A), the set of functions from Z to A. Using a diagonal argument, prove that this set is not countable. Hint: a set X is countable if there is a surjection Z → X."

In class, we saw how to use the argument to show that R is not countable. I have the impression that the proof to do for this exercise is the same, but it feels too easy (and all the time I think something is easy, it ends up that I was getting it wrong). Plus, I am a bit destabilized by the hint given in the exercise ! Could we do without?
On this website, the closest topic I could find is : [Find whether the following set is countable/uncountable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2252893/find-whether-the-following-set-is-countable-uncountable/2252951#2252951)  but they don't use the hint

For the moment this is what I wrote:

We want to show Fun(Z, A) is not countable. A function Z -> A has only two possible outputs (0 and 1) and s o function would look like that :
..., f(-5) = 0, f(-4) = 1, f(-3) = 1, f(-2) - 1, f(-1) = 0, f(0) =1, f(1) = 1, ...

So let's try to enumerate all the functions of this form :
for example
$$
.
.
.\\
e(-5) ..... 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 ...... \\
e(-4) ......1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 ......\\
e(-3) ......0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 ......\\
.
.
.
$$
Let's define a function X : Z -> A such that

X(i) = 
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if the i-th element of e(i) is 0} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}

In our example, X = ... 100 ...

Suppose there exist e(i) such that e(i) = X. But by construction of X, at the i-th element of e(i), $ X \neq e(i) $, so $ X \neq e(i) $ . This is a contradiction, there is no e(i) such that e(i) = X. Fun(Z, A) is not countable.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026902/let-a-be-a-set-of-all-infinite-sequences-consisting-of-0s-and-1s-prove-that-a/1026905

Comment: thank you ! Does it change anything to use : "Hint: a set X is countable if there is a surjection Z → X." (so using the surjection Z-> X instead of N-> X?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is quite correct. The only thing I would change (apart from formatting) is to clearly start the proof. Rather than saying "So let's try to enumerate all functions of this form:" you should say "So take an enumeration of functions of this form. We will show that at least one element is missing from the list." Then at the end you conclude that $X$ is not in the list, therefore indeed at least one element is missing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !! I will try to do better at formatting next time ! I read the tutorial on how to format math available on Stack, but I am still quite slow at it.